# Turtlebot Netbook Battery Error

Tags: ros, battery, turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

While launching the turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch that generally uses the "info" and "state" files to check the turtlebot laptop battery I get the following Error:

[WARN] [WallTime: 1360800362.124919] Battery : unable to check laptop battery info [[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info']

However in Ubuntu Quantal 12.10 these files no longer exist. Now they've broken the data into several different files located in /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0.

So I'm wondering if there is an updated script (which I haven't been able to find) or if the laptop_battery.py file needs to be changed in order to get it working, however I'm kind of new at this and that would take longer. =S

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55151/turtlebot-netbook-battery-error/) by [LCROBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/4196/lcrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

laptop_battery.py has evolved over time, as laptop vendors and driver developers don't follow any sort of standard for how they expose those stats. If you aren't using an official turtlebot laptop from either iHeartEngineering or Clearpath Robotics, chances are that your specific laptop isn't exactly supported. I would suggest posting a ticket on github.com/turtlebot with as much details as you have about the layout of your ACPI -- and of course, if you do get around to fixing it, please submit a pull request with your changes!

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1